# Evaluating a constant within a module

Tags: ruby, class, module, constants

When `class` keyword is used, constant lookup is done within that class. In the following, what is assigned to `:bar` is `B::A`, not `::A`.

```
A = :foo
class B
  A = :bar
end
A # => :foo
```

But in method definition, I cannot use the keyword `class`, and if I use things like `class_eval`, `module_eval`, `instance_eval`, to evaluate a block, then the constant referred to would be evaluated in the main environment as follows.

```
class B; end
def foo &pr
  B.class_eval(&pr)
end
foo{A = :bar}
A # => :bar
```

Is there a way to pass a block to a method and have its constant be evaluated within a certain class/module?

Comment: Why not just reference the constant with its intended scope `::A = :bar`? Makes it very clear what's going on then.

Comment: If you're going through the trouble to change a constant using an instance method, why even bother making a constant? Why not use an instance variable on the class? Or a class method?

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're asking (though I don't yet understand why you need to). You could yield the class back to the block so at least you're explicit about what is happening:

```
def foo &pr
  yield self.class
end

my_object.foo {|klass| klass::A = :bar }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Module#const_set](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-const_set) seems to be what you want:

```
class B; end

def foo(klass, konstant, val)
  klass.const_set(konstant, val)
end

foo(B, "A", :bar)

B::A #=> :bar
A    #=> NameError: uninitialized constant A
```

...but since you didn't mention it, I expect I've misunderstood the question.